# Algorithm for print circular list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to write the algorithm in this question (from a quiz, not homework):

> Write an algorithm of a function to
>   print out the information stored in a
>   circular list. Make sure that your
>   algorithms works for empty lists,
>   lists containing only one node, and
>   lists containing many nodes.

My algorithm prints info `<val list metadata>`. This algorithm prints the information in circular list.

```
if (newptr != null) // check is list empty or not
  firstnod = head // if it's not, save the first nod's data because it's circular list
  print newptr.data 
end if
loop (newptr.data != firstnod)
  print newptr.data 
  count += 1
end loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Need to update the `newptr` in the loop. Else, you will always get the same elements and is an infinite loop.

```
loop newptr != firstnod  
  print newptr.data  
  newptr = newptr.nextnode  
endloop
```

**Edit 1:**

```
if list != NULL
    print list.data
    if list.nextNode != NULL
       Node* head, temp
       head = list
       temp = list.nextNode
       while( temp != head )
          print temp.data
          temp = temp.nextNode
       End while
    else
       print "Next node is not intialized";
else
     print "List is empty";
```

Comment: ya but I increse count or is not enough

Comment: @hana - increasing the count doesn't make the pointer to point to next node in a linked list.

Comment: @hana - Loop is correct, but still the algorithm isn't perfect. Try it.

Comment: @hana - Check out my version. Though I amn't sure my version is correct and efficient too. It satisfies the given 3 conditions, I believe. Cross check it :)